# Como cambiar los elementos str de una matriz en numpy (python)

Tags: python

al tener el siguiente codigo

```
matriz = np.ones((2,2),dtype=str)
for i in range(len(matriz[0])):
    for j in range(len(matriz[0])):
        if i == j:
            matriz[i,j] = matriz[i,j] + np.str_("-ʎ")
print(matriz)
```

yo deseo que se agregue "-ʎ" a todos los elementos de la diagonal principal
pero al imprimir, solo me muestra la misma matriz, porque toma únicamente el primer carácter del string.
Mi pregunta es ¿Es posible crear la matriz sin que se coma el elemento que deseo ubicar?

Answer (score 0):

Los elementos de un `ndarray` son todos del mismo tipo y **tamaño**. Como lo creastes con "1", el largo vale uno para todos sus elementos y es inmodificable. Por eso sólo almacena el primer carácter cuando quieres modificar el contenido de la celda.

La solución es reemplazar el `dtype` con `object`, con lo que puedes usar strings de cualquier largo.

También tenemos que reemplazar `np.ones`, ya que inicializa las celdas con enteros, no con strings. Usaremos en cambio `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np

matriz = np.array([["1"] * 2] * 2, dtype=object)
for i in range(len(matriz[0])):
    matriz[i,i] = matriz[i,i] + "-ʎ"
print(matriz)
```

produce:

```
[['1-ʎ' '1']
 ['1' '1-ʎ']]
```

Comment: Graacias, me sirvió mucho